# Android: Passing a value with the button click using switch case

Tags: android, variable-assignment, switch-statement

I have two buttons when we click the first button we should assign M  value to a string and for the second button I want to assign F value to the same string variable

In the below given code gender is the string variable which is null and when we click the regmalebtn we should pass value M to the string  gender and F for second button

In the XML I haven't added set-text  to both the buttons. when I am doing this, null value is passing and I m getting null pointer exception.

how to solve this? any Help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance...!

```
    String gender = null; 
Button regmalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regmalebtn);
  Button regfemalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regfemalebtn);
     // Here in the above line I m getting the error//
  public void onClick(View v) {

      switch(v.getId()){

      case R.id.regmalebtn:

    //  gender = regmalebtn.getText().toString();
        gender.equals("M");
    //  request.addProperty("gender",gender );

           break;

      case R.id.regfemalebtn: 

       //  gender = regfemalebtn.getText().toString();
            gender.equals("F");
        //  request.addProperty("gender", gender);
           break;
      default:
          break;

      }
      }
```

Comment: gender.equals("M"); means you are comparing teh value of gender with M instead of you have to assign the value. example gender = "M"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do like this.

```
  Button regmalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regmalebtn);
  regmalebtn.setOnClickListener(this);

  Button regfemalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regfemalebtn);
  regfemalebtn .setOnClickListener(this);

   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
      switch(v.getId())
      {
          case R.id.regmalebtn:
                               gender = "M";
                               break;

         case R.id.regfemalebtn: 
                              gender = "F";
                              break;

         default:
                              break;
     }
   }
```

Comment: U want me to assign this where? inside switch case?

Comment: yes you have to set it into your switch case . Here i update my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,but its showing Syntax error on token "this", delete this token

Comment: have you implement onClickListener ?

Answer (score 1):

When you tried to use any of these statements:

```
//  gender = regmalebtn.getText().toString();
```

or

```
        gender.equals("F");
```

both of them are null.

And the correct way to assign a value to a variable is :

```
variable = value;
```

In your case, instead of:

```
gender.equals("F")
```

you use:

```
gender = "F"; // or gender = new String("F");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 **String gender = "";**  

 Button regmalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regmalebtn);
  regmalebtn.setOnClickListener(this);

  Button regfemalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regfemalebtn);
  regfemalebtn .setOnClickListener(this);

   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
      switch(v.getId())
      {
          case R.id.regmalebtn:
                               gender = "M";
                               break;

         case R.id.regfemalebtn: 
                              gender = "F";
                              break;

         default:
                              break;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 {
   String gen="";
  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     final TextView show= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    //Buttons and their values
        final Button male= (Button) findViewById(R.id.male);
        final Button female= (Button) findViewById(R.id.female);

        final View.OnClickListener gender =new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                final int id=v.getId();
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.male:{
                        show.setText("male");   //It will show gender in textView.
                        gen="male";
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.female:{
                        show.setText("female");
                        gen="female";
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        male.setOnClickListener(gender);
        female.setOnClickListener(gender);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your answer. Can you please add some context to this? Code is helpful, but insight into the reasoning behind the code is even more useful.